# Unit testing the Viewmodel

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, unit-testing, tdd

I am sort of new to TDD. I have started creating the properties I need on the view model as plain auto property.

```
public string Firstname { get; set; }
```

Then I create a test

```
[TestMethod]
[Tag("Property")]
public void FirstNameTest()
{
    ViewModel = new CustomerViewModel();
    ViewModel.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
                                     {
                                         Assert.AreEqual("Firstname", e.PropertyName);
                                         Assert.AreEqual("Test", ViewModel.Firstname);
                                     };
    ViewModel.Firstname = "Test";
}
```

Then I would extend the actual implementation to make the test pass like this:

```
public string Firstname
{
    get { return _contact.FirstName; }
    set
    {
        if (_contact.FirstName == value)
            return;

        _contact.FirstName = value;

        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Firstname);
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that test still passes for the Aut property. Any tip for me how i could improve my process?

Comment: You shouldn't place Asserts within a lambda. Asserts throw exceptions when they fail. If you do that within the lambdas, then those are going to fire inside the object-under-test and you run the risk of those being handled by the object. You should instead assign results to some (usually bool) variables from the test scope and then assert against those when you have returned and unwound the call stack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try writing the test to be asynchronous. Consider this test method:

```
[TestMethod]
[Asynchronous]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    TestViewModel testViewModel = new TestViewModel();

    bool firstNameChanged = false;

    testViewModel.PropertyChanged +=
        (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.PropertyName == "FirstName")
                {
                    firstNameChanged = true;
                }
            };

    EnqueueCallback(() => testViewModel.FirstName = "first name");
    EnqueueConditional(() => firstNameChanged == true);
    EnqueueTestComplete();
}
```

Notice the Asynchronous attribute at the top of the method. There are two important methods here: EnqueueCallback and EnqueueTestComplete. EnqueueCallback will add lambda expressions to a queue and the test method will wait until the current callback is executed. In the case here, we subscribe to the PropertyChanged event on the ViewModel and we set a local boolean variable to true when the FirstName property notifies a change. We then Enqueue two callbacks: one to set the FirstName property and one to assert that the local boolean variable has changed value. Finally, we need to add a call to EnqueueTestComplete() so that the framework knows the test is over.

NOTE: In order to get EnqueueCallback and EnqueueTestComplete, you need to inherit from SilverlightTest on your test class. You also need to import Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing to get the Asynchronous attribute. It should look something like this:

```
using Microsoft.Silverlight.Testing;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Foo.Example.Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Tests : SilverlightTest
    {

        // ... tests go here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer helped me on a Silverlight level even more. However I would like to comment on one thing, If you use EnqueueCallback without any case of EnqueueConditional, it would be the same as if you would make the calls synchronous anyway.

Comment: Yes, EnqueueConditional should be used to make a test truly wait for an event to fire. I guess I made my example a little too trivial, my apologies. It now uses EnqueueConditional to wait on the boolean state of firstNamedChanged to turn to true.

Answer (score 11):

You can do something like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [Tag("Property")]
    public void FirstNameTest()
    {
        bool didFire = false;
        ViewModel = new CustomerViewModel();
        ViewModel.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
                                         {
                                             didFire = true;
                                             Assert.AreEqual("Firstname", e.PropertyName);
                                             Assert.AreEqual("Test", ViewModel.Firstname);
                                         };
        ViewModel.Firstname = "Test";
        Assert.IsTrue(didFire);
    }
```

Comment: Many Thanks for the clear answer. It works now. However the Assert throws an AssertFailedException at the last line. I have to F5 it to continue and then I see the test has failed in the results. I am using Silverlight 4 Unit testing toolkit that comes with VS 2010. This is quite annoying, is it possible to suppress this, I don't want to F5 on 50 unit tests later on, if something went wrong. :)

Comment: Simply don't run the tests in debug mode :)

Comment: I ran it under Release and it still comes up with an interruption. Its very annoying. I am using unit testing under Silverlight 4 Test Framework. Any idea anyone?

Comment: i found it. It has nothing to do with debug mode the answer is here:
http://blog.benday.com/archive/2010/08/18/23287.aspx

Comment: @Antoine Aubry, alternatively he can hit the continue button or press F5. It's the same behavior.

Comment: Here's the archived version of the expired link above: https://web.archive.org/web/20100821113937/http://blog.benday.com/archive/2010/08/18/23287.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to have another test that actually asserts that your PropertyChanged even fires.

When you make that test, then your auto property should fail, because the event will never fire.

[Here's an example of how to do that in Moq](http://blog.decayingcode.com/2009/02/part-3-advanced-mocking-functionalities.html)

Comment: Many Thanks for the article, I will study it soon and see what else I could learn from it.

Comment: unfortunately, the link is dead and no information from the article is copied in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A test should fail unless the behavior it is testing is already implemented.

For testing property change notifications in my last attempt, I created [a helper class](http://code.google.com/p/gishu-util/source/browse/trunk/Beacons/Test.Beacons/Infrastructure/PropertyChangeListener.cs) that helped me write tests like this (It's in NUnit)

```
[Test]
public void NotifiesChangeIn_TogglePauseTooltip()
{
   var listener = new PropertyChangeListener(_mainViewModel);

   _mainViewModel.TogglePauseCommand.Execute(null);

   Assert.That(listener.HasReceivedChangeNotificationFor("TogglePauseTooltip"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I've done this in the past (I've used NUnit so it might be a bit different):

```
[Test]
public void ShouldNotifyListenersWhenFirstNameChanges()
{
    var propertiesChanged = new List<string>();

    ViewModel = new CustomerViewModel();
    ViewModel.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => propertiesChanged.Add(e.PropertyName);

    ViewModel.Firstname = "Test";

    Assert.Contains("Firstname", propertiesChanged);      
    Assert.AreEqual("Test", ViewModel.Firstname);  
}
```

Has the nice side-effect of being able to debug and work out what changed, if it wasn't the `Firstname`. Really handy when you've got multiple fields being calculated from other fields. You can also look at the other aspect of behaviour in your code:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldNotNotifyListenersWhenPropertiesAreNotChanged()
{
    var propertiesChanged = new List<string>();

    ViewModel = new CustomerViewModel();
    ViewModel.Firstname = "Test";

    ViewModel.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => propertiesChanged.Add(e.PropertyName);

    ViewModel.Firstname = "Test";

    Assert.AreEqual(0, propertiesChanged.Count); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps there is more background to this code that is not being revealed, but what I am seeing seems unnecessarily complicated.  Why bother hooking into the `RaisePropertyChanged` event at all?  Just check the property after setting it.

```
[TestMethod]
[Tag("Property")]
public void FirstNameTest()
{
    var expected = "John";
    var sut = new CustomerViewModel();

    sut.Firstname = expected;

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, sut.Firstname);
}
```

This also turns the test into a true unit test.

Comment: This would be somewhat useless. Why asset that the framework is able to correctly process the setter of an autoproperty? The test starts to make sense the moment you want to check that `PropertyChanged` events are raised as expected. **That** is the only thing worth checkling in such a test.

Comment: @Martin I would agree that testing the setter of an autoproperty would provide no benefit.  However, if you look at the original code (posted by Hooman) you will notice that the property is only set if the incoming value is not equal to the value in _contact.FirstName.  That is the portion of code with which my refactored test is concerned.