# Help Writing an Asynchronous Unit Test In Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, unit-testing, windows-phone-7

I am trying to write an Asynchronous Silverlight Unit Test, as mentioned in http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/silverlight/2.0/unittest.html. Perhaps I am struggling with lambda expressions, I am not sure, but I am unclear how to write my named callbacks so that the asynch test completes without exception. Currently it throws an System.UnauthorizedAccessException (Invalid cross-thread access) in the call the TestComplete(), which I am guessing is because it doesn't know it's still in the testNullInsert() test?

Question - how do I write the test correctly, and if I need lambda expressions, please explain what does what please.

Below is my code so far:

```
[TestClass]
public class IdentityEditDatabaseTest : WorkItemTest
{
  [TestMethod, Asynchronous] public void testNullInsert()
  {
    wipeTestData(testNullInsertContinue1);
  }
  private void testNullInsertContinue1(String errorString)
  {
    IdentityProperties properties = new IdentityProperties(getContext());
    properties.setUserName(DATABASE_TEST);
    postUserEdit(properties, testNullInsertContinue2);
  }
  private void testNullInsertContinue2(String errorString)
  {
    Assert.assertTrue(errorString == null);

    wipeTestData(testNullInsertContinue3);
  }
  private void testNullInsertContinue3(String errorString)
  {
    TestComplete();
  }
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Correct code is below, thanks to @ajmccall's [link](http://jonas.follesoe.no/2008/06/04/unit-testing-asynchronous-silverlight-code/)!

```
[TestClass]
public class IdentityEditDatabaseTest : DatabaseTestCase
{
  [TestMethod, Asynchronous] public void testNullInsert()// throws Throwable
  {
    EnqueueCallback(() => wipeTestData(errorString1 => {

    IdentityProperties properties = new IdentityProperties(getContext());
    properties.setUserName(DATABASE_TEST);
    EnqueueCallback(() => postUserEdit(properties, errorString2 => {

    Assert.assertTrue(errorString2 == null);

    EnqueueCallback(() => wipeTestData(errorString3 => {

    EnqueueTestComplete();
  }));
  }));
  }));
  }
```

Comment: Invalid cross-thread access exception is due to the back ground thread tryring to access resources of UI thread or vice versa.

Comment: Sure, but it happens in the line "TestComplete()", which is an asynch callback called by the system, indirectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that @Anthony is right in suggesting that `TestComplete()` makes some call to the UI thread, and since it's called from a background thread (because it's a callback), it causes this exception to be thrown.

From reading the docs now, it says of the `[Asynchronous]` tag

> The test has completed only after the TestComplete method is called, not when the method exits. Your test class must inherit from SilverlightTest to perform asynchronous tests

You could try putting the line `TestComplete()` at the end of your `testNullInsert` method. This may not throw the exception, but I don't think it'll be performing the test properly. What you ultimately want to do is have one test method which does the following steps,

> - Clear the test data and wait until it finishes - this is not the test, so are not concerned about the results but we still have to wait using a AutoResetEvent or continuing inside the callback
> - Define the callback that you want to test
> - Add the callback to the unit test queue - using EnqueueCallback()
> - Wait for the callback to finish and store result - using EnqueueConditional()
> - Inform the unti test framework you've finish - by calling EnqueueTestComplete()

If you can rewrite your test into something that looks like [this](http://jonas.follesoe.no/2008/06/04/unit-testing-asynchronous-silverlight-code/), then I think you'll be on your way to writing asynchronous unit tests for your code.

Cheers,
Al.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things that will happen on `TestComplete` is the UI will be updated.  However evidently the `TestComplete` method (or the UI code that it eventually interacts with) is not expecting to be called on a non-UI thread.

Hence it would seem its up to you to ensure the call to `TestComplete` is executed on the UI thread:-

```
  private void testNullInsertContinue3(String errorString)
  {
       Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(TestComplete); 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this later today. So I don't need to make any EnqueueCallback() anywhere?

Comment: Works like a charm! The only weird thing is that when the test passes, it doesn't show up in the test runner. However, if it fails, it does fail (with an error that a result was already set for that test case). Not ideal, but it does the trick for what i need. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, the test doesn't wait for the test to complete and starts running my other tests in parallel, which causes other problems. I think this is related to the two comments above. See also post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845332/tdd-unit-testing-the-viewmodel. Any thoughts Anthony?